# Redirect to login page without using spring security

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to spring and creating an web application ,
 I want to redirect to login page always when user is not authenticated and without using spring security.xml??
Is it possible with session management??

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to use a 'HandlerInterceptorAdapator':

```
public class CheckUserInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Resource
    private UserSession userSession;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Object handler) throws IOException {

        if (request.getServletPath().equals("/login.htm")) {
            return true;
        }

        String username = userSession.getUsername();

        // If the username has not been set by the login controller    
        if (username != null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("login.htm");
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

In this case you need to declare the interceptor in the Spring XML file:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="fr.unilim.msi.dad.web.mvc.CheckUserInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Another approach, if for instance your Spring MVC controller are not configured to handle all requests, is to use a filter at the servlet level:

```
public class AccessControlFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession(true);
        User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
        if (user == null) {
            String urlRoot = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getContextPath();
            ((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect(urlRoot + "/login.jsp");
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do something like below in your login controller:

```
if(isUserAuthenticated())
{
    return "home";
}
else
{ 
    session.invalidate();
    return "redirect:login";
}
```

Comment: This is not a global access control mechanism: you need to add code in each controller to check session (it is better to enforce this behavior globally on each request to the Spring main controller).